# React js user tabel data added dynamically how to find user name

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I am create asp.net core web api crud project and user add and update data .My question is which user add a data and update data how to find give solution.

My table datas which user added and updated how to show give solutions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.